# (Pandas, Python) How can I match str data between 2 different dataframes, and then add a value as a column based on the match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To elaborate, I have 2 dataframes. Both dataframes have a name column. `DF1['Name']` is shaped (28,) and `DF2['Name']` is shaped (67,). All instances of names in `DF1['Name']` should be found in `DF2['Name']`.
DF2 also has a role column, is it possible to find all matching instances between the df's and then adding the roles for the matching elements between the dataframes?

I have tried `DF1['Name'].eq(df2['Name']` which I know returns Boole T/Fs, however when I attempt, it returns F for all elements, which I know is because the indexes are not matching.

I have tried `s = df1.where(df1['Name'].values==df2['Name'].values)`
which returns ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self

I believe that `pd.findall()` might be a valid solution, but I am unsure.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: To add more clarification, in DF2, all names are assigned a role. All names from DF1['Names'] exist in DF2['Names], where those string values == is there a way I would be able to add in a column to df1 where the corresponding role values from df2 are added?

Comment: I know from the lack of code provided it might be difficult to believe. But I've spent hours trying to figure this small issue out. The only results I seem to be able to get are comparison errors, errors because the data referenced was object until it was converted to string, and further, I've tried eq, str.contains, perhaps a nested for loop might be worth while, or maybe sorting the index names?

Comment: A [mcve] would clarify things further... But as far as I understood, is `df1["roles"] = df1.name.map(dict(zip(df2.name, df2.roles)))` working? This first forms a mapping from `df2`s `"name"` & `"roles"` columns and then using this, `map`s the `"name"` column of the `df1` and assigns the result to a new column called `"roles"` in `df1`.

Comment: Hello, Mustafa: Yes, I believe this has worked beautifully, it seems to provide all of the functionality that I need it to with all of the roles as intended. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Suppose:**

```
data1={'Process_ID':['12345-98', '23547-75', '85763-99','44231-56','78456-00','53218-87'],
     'Date': ['2021-06-30','2022-08-10','2021-06-15','2023-10-02','2024-04-03','2021-06-25'],
     'Check': ['True','False','False','True','True','False']}

df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)

df1.head()
Process_ID  Date    Check
0   12345-98    2021-06-30  True
1   23547-75    2022-08-10  False
2   85763-99    2021-06-15  False
3   44231-56    2023-10-02  True
4   78456-00    2024-04-03  True

data2={'abc_ID':['12345-98', '23544-75', '85713-99','44231-56','78456-00','53218-87'],
     'Date': ['2021-06-30','2022-08-11','2021-06-12','2023-10-02','2024-04-03','2021-06-25'],
     'xyz': ['True','False','False','True','True','False']}

df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)

df2.head()
abc_ID  Date    xyz
0   12345-98    2021-06-30  True
1   23544-75    2022-08-11  False
2   85713-99    2021-06-12  False
3   44231-56    2023-10-02  True
4   78456-00    2024-04-03  True
```

**Merge using common column 'Date:**

```
full_df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='Date', how='outer')
full_df.head(10)
```

[full_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjtxO.png)

**Drop rows contain Null Value:**

```
full_df = full_df.dropna()
full_df.head(10)
```

[full_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfiYE.png)

Comment: I appreciate the response Nikunj, I ran into a few problems with the merge method, mostly that it was appending the remainder of the difference of the 40 or so instances from the second dataframe. When I dropped NA, I lost pretty much all data in the frame because of the NaN values supplied in the dataset